# create a Filters provider (context) to save mupltiple useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a simple React application that is composed by two selects so the user can choose a color and a year from two dropdowns.

I created to react states in the App component and I pass to the children the current states and the functions to update them.

Here the core:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("red");
  const [year, setYear] = useState("2005");

  return (
    <div className="">
      <FiltersWrapper
        color={color}
        setColor={(color: string) => setColor(color)}
        year={year}
        setYear={(year: string) => setYear(year)}
      />

      <br />

      <Result color={color} year={year} />
    </div>
  );
}

export const FiltersWrapper: FC<FiltersWrapperProps> = ({
  color,
  setColor,
  year,
  setYear
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        id="color-select"
        options={[
          { value: "red", label: "Red" },
          { value: "blue", label: "Blue" },
          { value: "purple", label: "Purple" }
        ]}
        value={color}
        onChange={(color: string) => setColor(color)}
        title="Select a color:"
      />

      <Select
        id="year-select"
        options={[
          { value: "2000", label: "2000" },
          { value: "2005", label: "2005" },
          { value: "2010", label: "2010" },
          { value: "2015", label: "2015" },
          { value: "2020", label: "2020" }
        ]}
        value={year}
        onChange={(year: string) => setYear(year)}
        title="Select a year:"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export const Select: FC<SelectProps> = ({
  id,
  options,
  value,
  onChange,
  title
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      {title && <label htmlFor={id}>{title}</label>}

      <select
        id={id}
        value={value}
        onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
          onChange(event.target.value);
        }}
      >
        {options.map((option, i) => {
          return (
            <option key={i} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export const Result: FC<ResultProps> = ({ color, year }) => {
  return <div>{`selected: ${color}, ${year}`}</div>;
};
```

Here the demo.

It works, but I'm asking if I can use a Filter context that wraps the main component with the provider, something like this:

```js
export interface Filters {
  color: string;
  year: string;
}

const FilterContext = createContext<Filters>({
  color: "",
  year: ""
});

export const FilterProvider: FC<PropsWithChildren<{ filters: Filters }>> = ({
  filters,
  children
}) => (
  <FilterContext.Provider value={filters}>{children}</FilterContext.Provider>
);

export const useFilters = () => useContext(FilterContext);

// ---

export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("red"); // ??
  const [year, setYear] = useState("2005"); // ??

  return (
    <div>
      <FiltersWrapper
        color={color}
        setColor={(color: string) => setColor(color)}
        year={year}
        setYear={(year: string) => setYear(year)}
      />
      <Result color={color} year={year} />
    </div>
  );
}

export const FiltersWrapper: FC<FiltersWrapperProps> = ({
  color,
  setColor,
  year,
  setYear
}) => {
  return (
    <FilterProvider filters={{ color, year }}>
      <Select
        id="color-select"
        options={[
          { value: "red", label: "Red" },
          { value: "blue", label: "Blue" },
          { value: "purple", label: "Purple" }
        ]}
        value={color}
        onChange={(color: string) => setColor(color)}
        title="Select a color:"
      />
      <Select
        id="year-select"
        options={[
          { value: "2000", label: "2000" },
          { value: "2005", label: "2005" },
          { value: "2010", label: "2010" },
          { value: "2015", label: "2015" },
          { value: "2020", label: "2020" }
        ]}
        value={year}
        onChange={(year: string) => setYear(year)}
        title="Select a year:"
      />
    </FilterProvider>
  );
};
```

but how can I define the `setYear` and `setColor` functions in the `FiltersProvider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick implementation that should get you started. This first example does not include the Filter in the context.

Context declaration:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export type FilterContextType = { 
    color: string;
    setColor: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
    year: string;
    setYear: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
};

export const FilterContext = createContext<FilterContextType>({
    color: "",
    setColor: () => {},
    year: "",
    setYear: () => {}
});
```

Then use the context within your filter component:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import Select from "./Select";
import { FilterContext } from "./FilterContext";

export const FiltersWrapper = () => {

    const { color, setColor, year, setYear } = useContext(FilterContext);

    return (
        <div>
            <Select
                id="color-select"
                options={[
                    { value: "red", label: "Red" },
                    { value: "blue", label: "Blue" },
                    { value: "purple", label: "Purple" }
                ]}
                value={color}
                onChange={(color: string) => setColor(color)}
                title="Select a color:"
            />

            <Select
                id="year-select"
                options={[
                    { value: "2000", label: "2000" },
                    { value: "2005", label: "2005" },
                    { value: "2010", label: "2010" },
                    { value: "2015", label: "2015" },
                    { value: "2020", label: "2020" }
                ]}
                value={year}
                onChange={(year: string) => setYear(year)}
                title="Select a year:"
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Also use the context in your result component:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { FilterContext } from "./FilterContext";

const Result = () => {

    const { color, year } = useContext(FilterContext);

    return (
        <div>
            <span>{color}</span><span>{year}</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And finally tie it all together by creating your context in the parent for both components - in this case the App component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import FiltersWrapper from './FilterWrapper';
import { FilterContext } from './FilterContext';
import Result from './Result';

function App() {

    const [color, setColor] = useState("red");
    const [year, setYear] = useState("2005");

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <FilterContext.Provider value={{color: color, setColor: setColor, year: year, setYear: setYear}}>
                <FiltersWrapper />
                <br />
                <Result />
            
            </FilterContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**The following shows the inclusion of the filter in the context**:
Note: if you are going to include JSX elements/syntax in the context you will need to ensure the file extension is .jsx or .tsx otherwise you will get errors in the provider declaration.

```
import { FC, createContext, useState } from "react";
import Select from "./Select";

export type FilterContextType = { 
    color: string;
    year: string;
};

export const FilterContext = createContext<FilterContextType | null>(null);

export const FilterProvider: FC<{children: any}> = 
   ({children }) => {

   const [color, setColor] = useState("red");
   const [year, setYear] = useState("2005");

   return (
       <FilterContext.Provider value={{color: color, year: year}}>
           <div>
               <Select
                   id="color-select"
                   options={[
                       { value: "red", label: "Red" },
                       { value: "blue", label: "Blue" },
                       { value: "purple", label: "Purple" }
                   ]}
                   value={color}
                   onChange={(color: string) => setColor(color)}
                   title="Select a color:"
               />
    
               <Select
                   id="year-select"
                   options={[
                       { value: "2000", label: "2000" },
                       { value: "2005", label: "2005" },
                       { value: "2010", label: "2010" },
                       { value: "2015", label: "2015" },
                       { value: "2020", label: "2020" }
                   ]}
                   value={year}
                   onChange={(year: string) => setYear(year)}
                   title="Select a year:"
               />
           </div>
           {children}
        </FilterContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Then Result component:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { FilterContext, FilterContextType } from "./FilterContext";

const Result = () => {

    const {color, year} = useContext(FilterContext) as FilterContextType;

    return (
        <div>
            <span>{color}</span>
            <span>{year}</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And finally App:

```
import './App.css';
import { FilterProvider } from './FilterContext';
import Result from './Result';

function App() {

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <FilterProvider>
                <Result />
            </FilterProvider>
        </div>
    );
}
```